# Jquery Customize Datatable exportoptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my datatable I have some columns with data like this: 'XXXX unit'.
When I export it I want to remove the unit part.

What is the rule I should put here?

```
exportOptions: {
      columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following function will remove " unit" from the end of every cell in column 2 (offset index 1) in the body of a table:

```
exportOptions: {
  format: {
    body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
      return column === 1 ? data.replace( / unit/g, '' ) : data;
    }
  }
}
```

This example uses `replace()` but there are other ways, of course.

In my case, here is how I placed the above option in my `buttons` section:

```
buttons: [
  $.extend ( 
    true, 
    {}, 
    { exportOptions: {
      format: {
        body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
          return column === 1 ? data.replace( / unit/g, '' ) : data;
        }
      }
    } }, 
    { extend: 'excel' } 
  )
]
```

There is an example [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-function.html) which also shows how to extract the `exportOptions` into re-usable code, if you want to apply it to multiple buttons.